# Squaring is linear in a field of characteristic 2

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

In [this paper](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/block-cipher-techniques/documents/bcm/comments/cwc-gcm/ferguson2.pdf), the following is asserted:

> The function
> $$X\to X^2$$ in $\mathrm{GF}(2^{128})$ is linear.
> This is due to the fact that $\mathrm{GF}(2^{128})$ is a field of characteristic 2, which implies that $\forall A, B, \quad (A+B)^2 = A^2 + B^2$.
>
> Thus, there is a fixed matrix $M_S$ such that $\overline{X^2} = M_S \overline{X}$
> for all $X$. Note that $M_S$ does not depend on anything except the chosen field representation, which is public.

(Here $\overline{X}$ is the vector of coefficients in $\mathrm{GF}(2)$ of the polynomial representation of X.)

I don't find this explanation very helpful. My question is thus: what is the reasoning why the fixed matrix $M_S$ exists?

And, what does the matrix $M_S$ look like?

Comment: sorry, that was unclear. I meant: why does it hold that there is a fixed matrix $M_S$ such that $\overline{X^2} = M_S\overline{X}$ for all $X$. I will edit the question.

Comment: Because it's a linear map, say $f$. Thus $f(x)=Ax$ with a matrix $A$. Therefore the section is called "Squaring is linear".

Comment: After fixing a basis of a vector space $V$ over the field $K$, linear maps $V \to V$ are in one-to-one correspondence with $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $K$ (where $n = \dim V$). In order to see what $M_S$ looks like, you need to figure out what squaring does in terms of the chosen basis, which you could try over the field with four or eight elements to get a feel for the computations involved.

Comment: my question is really: why is it a linear map?

Comment: Squaring is linear, because $g(x)=x^2$ satisfies $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$ and $g(\lambda x)=\lambda g(x)$. That's the definition of linear. The scalars here are only $1$ and $0$.

Comment: The simple fact here is that $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$ as usual, but $2xy=0$ because $2=0$. So $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2$.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the squaring map is $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear, not $\mathbb{F}_{128}$-linear. It is true in general that $(\lambda x)^2= \lambda x^2$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}_2$ and $x \in \mathbb{F}_{128}$, _not_ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}_{128}$. This is a general fact: if $p$ is a prime and $q = p^k$ is some power, then the $p$-th power map in $\mathbb{F}_q$ is $\mathbb{F}_p$-linear, but not necessarily $\mathbb{F}_q$-linear.

Comment: this answers my question -- thank you everyone.

Comment: @DietrichBurde what does the matrix representation of $g$ look like? Since $0^2 = 0$ and $1^2 = 1$, is it just the identity matrix? Or should I think of $x$ as taking on values other than $0$ and $1$?